# Issue passing function arguments dynamically to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was pulling my hair trying to fix a bug on some two dimensional list manipulations.
The following script simply initializes a few empty lists, then does basic calculations and returns the output.
The problem occurs when I call the main function, here is the code:

```
dataList=[]
outputList1=[]
outputList2=[]
fileData=["a","b","c"]

def initialize(*args):
    global dataList

    dataList=[[]for j in range(len(fileData))] #initialize the array with empty lists
    for x in range(len(fileData)):
        for y in range(12):
            dataList[x].append(y) #populates the list with data

    for x in args:
        for y in range(len(fileData)):
            x[1][2].append([]) #initializes the output lists with empty lists

def functionAdd(number, inputList, outputList):#basic data manipulation
    for y in range(len(inputList)):
        for x in range(len(inputList[y])):
            outputList[y].append(inputList[y][x]+number)

def functionSubstract(number, inputList, outputList):#other basic manipulation
    for y in range(len(inputList)):
        for x in range(len(inputList[y])):
            outputList.append(inputList[y][x]-number)

def mainFunction(*args):#unpacks the function names to be executed, as well as their arguments
    for x in args:
        x[0](*x[1])

f1=[functionAdd,(2,dataList,outputList1)]#variable of a function to be executed
f2=[functionSubstract,(3.5,dataList,outputList2)]#variable of a function to be executed

initialize(f1,f2)#this part works fine
mainFunction(f1,f2)#this part does't work
##mainFunction([functionAdd,(2,dataList,outputList1)],[functionSubstract,(3.5,dataList,outputList2)])
print(outputList1)
```

The initialization goes without issues with (initialize(f1,f2)), it unpacks the arguments and creates empty sub-lists in the corresponding list to make a 2-dimensional array.

However, when I try to call the "mainFunction" the same way, the print statement displays: [[], [], []], so basically no calculation has been done to it.

But, when I un-comment the last line and instead call the mainFunction in this way:

```
mainFunction([functionAdd,(2,dataList,outputList1)],[functionSubstract,(3.5,dataList,outputList2)])
```

then I get the correct output, and the print statement displays:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

which is the correct result.
So I finally got the function to work, but I still don't understand what's wrong with the previous syntax of calling it

```
mainFunction(f1,f2)
```

because in both cases I call the function with the exact same arguments...

Can anyone care to explain? Thanks,

Comment: You're reassigning dataList in your initialise function. It's no longer the same object you've passed to f1 & f2. Remove the `dataList=` from the initialise function and insert `dataList.append([])` after `for x in range(len(fileData)):` and it should do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `initialize` function, you are assigning a new value (a list) to the variable `dataList`, while the variable `dataList` in:

```
f1=[functionAdd,(2,dataList,outputList1)]
f2=[functionSubstract,(3.5,dataList,outputList2)]
```

is the previously assigned variable `dataList`.

You can check this with `id()`, which shows the unique ID of an object in python:

```
dataList=[]
outputList1=[]
outputList2=[]
fileData=["a","b","c"]

print(f'Initial dataList, ID: {id(dataList)}')

def initialize(*args):
    global dataList

    dataList = [[] for j in range(len(fileData))]  # initialize the array with empty lists
    for x in range(len(fileData)):
        for y in range(12):
            dataList[x].append(y) #populates the list with data

    for x in args:
        for y in range(len(fileData)):
            x[1][2].append([]) #initializes the output lists with empty lists

    print(f'dataList in f1 & f2, ID: {id(args[1][1][1])}')
    print(f'dataList after reassigning dataList, ID: {id(dataList)}')


def functionAdd(number, inputList, outputList):#basic data manipulation
    for y in range(len(inputList)):
        for x in range(len(inputList[y])):
            outputList[y].append(inputList[y][x]+number)

def functionSubstract(number, inputList, outputList):#other basic manipulation
    for y in range(len(inputList)):
        for x in range(len(inputList[y])):
            outputList.append(inputList[y][x]-number)

def mainFunction(*args):#unpacks the function names to be executed, as well as their arguments
    for x in args:
        x[0](*x[1])

f1=[functionAdd,[2,dataList,outputList1]]#variable of a function to be executed
f2=[functionSubstract,[3.5,dataList,outputList2]]#variable of a function to be executed

initialize(f1,f2)#this part works fine
mainFunction(f1,f2)#this part does't work
##mainFunction([functionAdd,(2,dataList,outputList1)],[functionSubstract,(3.5,dataList,outputList2)])
print(outputList1)
```

Output:

```
>>>Initial dataList, ID: 2168655372096
>>>dataList in f1 & f2, ID: 2168655372096
>>>dataList after reassigning dataList, ID: 2168657467648
>>>[[], [], []]
```

You can see now that after the statement `dataList = [[] for j in range(len(fileData))]`, the dataList's ID has changed. You are actually doing the calculations with the new variable `dataList` instead of the old variable `dataList` in `f1`&`f2`. This is why you don't get the correct output when calling `mainFunction(f1,f2)`.

Calling `mainFunction([functionAdd,(2,dataList,outputList1)],[functionSubstract,(3.5,dataList,outputList2)])` does give you the correct output because you now pass in the new variable `dataList`, which had the calculations.

You should do operations with the same variable `dataList`, instead of reassigning the variable `dataList`.

Example:

```
dataList=[]
outputList1=[]
outputList2=[]
fileData=["a","b","c"]

print(f'Initial dataList, ID: {id(dataList)}')

def initialize(*args):
    global dataList

    for i in range(len(fileData)): #initialize the array with empty lists
        dataList.append([])

    for x in range(len(fileData)):
        for y in range(12):
            dataList[x].append(y) #populates the list with data

    for x in args:
        for y in range(len(fileData)):
            x[1][2].append([]) #initializes the output lists with empty lists

    print(f'dataList in f1 & f2, ID: {id(args[1][1][1])}')
    print(f'dataList after operations with dataList, ID: {id(dataList)}')


def functionAdd(number, inputList, outputList):#basic data manipulation
    for y in range(len(inputList)):
        for x in range(len(inputList[y])):
            outputList[y].append(inputList[y][x]+number)

def functionSubstract(number, inputList, outputList):#other basic manipulation
    for y in range(len(inputList)):
        for x in range(len(inputList[y])):
            outputList.append(inputList[y][x]-number)

def mainFunction(*args):#unpacks the function names to be executed, as well as their arguments
    for x in args:
        x[0](*x[1])

f1=[functionAdd,[2,dataList,outputList1]]#variable of a function to be executed
f2=[functionSubstract,[3.5,dataList,outputList2]]#variable of a function to be executed

initialize(f1,f2)#this part works fine
mainFunction(f1,f2)#this part does't work
##mainFunction([functionAdd,(2,dataList,outputList1)],[functionSubstract,(3.5,dataList,outputList2)])
print(outputList1)
```

Output:

```
>>>Initial dataList, ID: 2560807861056
>>>dataList in f1 & f2, ID: 2560807861056
>>>dataList after operations with dataList, ID: 2560807861056
>>>[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Comment: Nice, indeed your solution fixed it. Since I was calling "global dataList", I thought that the list comprehension syntax would still point to that object, but yeah doing it with the append method is better. Thanks,